# Can I define a probability function in extRemes, or other Extreme Value packages in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I was wondering if I can define a function in the package extRemes (or other EV package?). For instance, to define the Gumbel in fitdistrplus, we can do:

```
dgumbel <- function(x, a, b) 1/b*exp((a-x)/b)*exp(-exp((a-x)/b))
pgumbel <- function(q, a, b) exp(-exp((a-q)/b))
qgumbel <- function(p, a, b) a-b*log(-log(p))
```

But when I try that using fevd (from extRemes), it doesn't work.

```
fit1 <- fevd(as.vector(x), method = "MLE", type="NewDistr")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you would like to specify a nonstandard value for the `type` parameter. However, the corresponding error

```
# Error in match.arg(type) : 
#   'arg' should be one of “GEV”, “GP”, “PP”, “Gumbel”, “Exponential”
```

is quite self-explanatory in saying that it is not possible.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen, I'm not addressing "other EV packages" because such questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Fair enough. If you know it, however, you can probably indicate it here as a comment.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen, I sure would, but unfortunately I don't know.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot though @JuliusVainora